# In an instance, how can I detect when a class member is being replaced with a new instance member?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class ReplaceableClass(Object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = [x]

    def movedata(self, old):
        self.x = old.x + self.x

class Example(Object):

    myThing = ReplaceableClass(1) 

e = Example()

e.myThing = ReplaceableClass(2)
```

How can it work as if I replace the last line by the following block?

```
myNewThing = ReplaceableClass(2)
myNewThing.movedata(e.myThing)
e.myThing = myNewThing
```

So `e.myThing.x` equals [1,2] instead of [2].

I tried by using descriptors, but it can't assign a new object because it causes an infinite loop:

```
class ReplaceableClass(Object):

    [...]

    def __set__(self,a,b):
        for p in dir(a):
            if self==getattr(a,p):
                self.movedata(b)
```

Comment: It may be *possible* but it certainly won't be idiomatic, advisable, maintainable, sane, useful or in good taste.

Comment: Sorry, my question is too vague to grasp how useful may it be.

Comment: No matter how useful it may appear, the other drawbacks cancel that out and leave you with a net loss. Remember: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Ok, I'll set a .replace() method instead of implicit magic, but the solution offered here will be useful nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- Use `self.__dict__` in `movedata` to avoid the infinite loop. `self.__dict__` is the raw dictionary which contains all the properties in an instance; if you access the dict directly, you will not invoke the methods used by the descriptor API.
- If you only have a couple of properties, you can use the properties API (see [the property() function](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html#properties)) instead which allows you to do something when a specific property changes (in this case, that would be `myThing`).

Comment: What do you mean by "the properties api"?

Comment: @Marcin `property` I'd wager.

Comment: Thank you!! Using `a.__dict__[p]=b` after movedata works exactly as I wanted!

Comment: @Marcin: The `property()` function. I enhanced my answer.

Comment: Using property(), you wrap a member variable so that when you try to assign to it or get its value, you call a function instead (which you define). That way you can save all incoming values in an array behind the scenes. It can be far cleaner than doing it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If i have caught idea you could do this as simple as

```
class Example(object):
    myThing = (1,)

e = Example()
e.myThing+= (2,)

>>> e.myThing
(1, 2)
>>> Example.myThing
(1,)
```

If you need more functionality, you could extend `tuple` or create your own immutable collection:

```
from itertools import chain
class ReplaceableClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *x):
        self._data = tuple(x)

    def __add__ (self, other):
        return ReplaceableClass(*(chain(self, other)))

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data )


    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ReplaceableClass(%s)'%(', '.join(map(repr,self._data)))

class Example(object):
    myThing = ReplaceableClass(1)

e = Example()
e.myThing+= (2,3)

>>> e.myThing
ReplaceableClass(1, 2, 3)
>>> Example.myThing
ReplaceableClass(1)
```